# iPhone - is there any way to look at the core data store for a live app?

Tags: iphone, core-data, live, inspect

I've got a live app on the app store that's producing some strange results when the user upgrades versions that I can't reproduce in my dev environment.  Does anyone know of a way to inspect the core data store of a live iPhone app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What do you mean by live? As it is running (with something like a debugger)? Or just "real-life end-user data" from an installed application?

In the latter case [extracting](http://supercrazyawesome.com/) the SQLite database contents from an iPhone backup could be of help.

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguity - i meant "real-life end-user data".  That should do the trick. Thanks!